# Why was BERT's default vocabulary size set to 30522?

Tags: tokenize, bert-language-model

I have been trying to build a BERT model for a specific domain. However, my model is trained on non-English text, so I'm worried that the default token size, 30522, won't fit my model.

Does anyone know where the number 30522 came from?

I expect that researchers were fine-tuning their model by focusing on training time and vocabulary coverage, but a more clear explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of 30522 is not "token size." It's the size of WordPiece vocabulary BERT was trained on. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382596/how-is-wordpiece-tokenization-helpful-to-effectively-deal-with-rare-words-proble) for an explanation of WordPiece. The number 30522 likely means the base character set was 522 characters in size and the WordPiece algorithm was trained on 30,000 iterations.